# Replace Python nested For Loops with comprehension

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

I'm looking for a way to use list comprehensions to achieve the following:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [5,6,7,8]
vals = []

for i in a:
  for j in b:
    vals.append(i*j)

print(vals)
```

I'm convinced there's a way to do this with list comprehension, but I'm at a loss for how to proceed.

Comment: vals = [i*j for i, j in zip(a,b)]

Comment: It may be a duplicate, but not of the one you mentioned - that solution gives me a list of lists; I'm not interested in having a list of lists, I want a list of all the values.  Run my code and then the code you referenced and you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pure list comprehension:

```
[i*j for i in a for j in b]
```

Output:

```
[5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 15, 18, 21, 24, 20, 24, 28, 32]
```

Comment: I posted that answer then deleted because I saw something (that didn't exist). I think it is becoming late for me today :) +1 for the brain telematics!

Answer (score 1):

itertools' [`product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) will give you all the combinations of elements from both lists. You could then use a comprehension to multiply each pair:

```
from itertools import product
print([x[0] * x[1] for x in product(a, b)])
```